Requires a primary key to be defined
I have a model class Attribute.
When I'm trying to add a migration
dotnet ef migrations add Attributes

I get the following error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The entity type 'Attribute' requires a primary key to be defined.

public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

I've tried configure file. Alas the same error occurs. [Key] also doesn't help
public class AtributeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Atribute>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Atribute> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);
    }
}

My OnModelCreating method:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DbContext).Assembly);
}


builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DbContext).Assembly);

That is going to look for configurations in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll which is where Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext is defined.
You want typeof(your-class-derived-from-dbContent).

The same error. Used IDbContext there

@user26589338 that would be expected, because IDbContext is also defined by the EF Core library (in assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll). You need to pass the assembly in which you define your entity and configuration types; because this is usually where your context class (derived from DbContext) is defined that is the one most programs use.

In IDbContext I put DbSet Atributes { get; set; }. You mean this?

@user26589338 It would help if your type derived from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext was in the question. If you have called your type DbContext you will only make things confusing. ApplicsationContext is a common name.
